# Unity mapbox - coordinates at center of zoomable map?

Tags: unity-game-engine, mapbox

I know how to move the zoomable map to a specific lat/long, and that point will be centered in the screen. If the user moves the map (drags it sideways), how do I get the coordinates at the point of the map that is now centered?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to use the Camera.ScreenToWorldPoint method from Unity:

https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Camera.ScreenToWorldPoint.html?_ga=2.95757022.39200391.1587116665-1246420375.1587116665

Please also have a look at this similar thread:
https://forum.unity.com/threads/how-to-get-a-world-position-from-the-center-of-the-screen.524573/

Answer (score 0):

Thanks! 
Based on the similar thread you pointed me to, I added a function to my QuadTreeCameraMovement...

```
public Vector2d GeoCoordsAtCenter() {
        var centerScreen = _referenceCamera.ViewportToScreenPoint(new Vector3(.5f, .5f, _referenceCamera.transform.localPosition.y));

        var pos = _referenceCamera.ScreenToWorldPoint(centerScreen);

        var latlongDelta = _mapManager.WorldToGeoPosition(pos);
        Debug.Log("CENTER: Latitude: " + latlongDelta.x + " Longitude: " + latlongDelta.y);
        return latlongDelta;
    }
```